# Strange behaviour on logical AND-Operators

Tags: php, operators, boolean-expression

Is anybody able to exlain this behaviour:

```
<?php

$var1 = true;

$var2 = 0;

$var3 = $var1 AND $var2;

var_export($var3); // Output: true

var_export(true AND 0); // Output: false    

var_export($var1 AND $var2); // Output: false
```

Output comes from PHP 7.0

Why is the first output `true` while the 3rd output is `false`?

By the way: it doesnt matter if `$var2` is `0` or `false`. The behaviour is the same.

@all: I know that I SHOULD use `&&` and I always do!

Comment: have you tried with &&,its gives same for all cases

Comment: @treyBake Not. `&&` is different from `AND`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually comes because `&&` is different from `AND`.

```
$var1 = true;
$var2 = 0;

$var3 = $var1 && $var2;
var_export($var3); // Output: false

$var3 = $var1 AND $var2;
var_export($var3); // Output: true
```

In the `&&` case you actually write `$var3 = ( $var1 && $var2 )`

In the `AND` case you actually write `( $var3 = $var1 ) AND $var2`

That's because `=` has greater precedence then `AND`, but `&&` has greater precedence then `=`

Answer (score 2):

It's because of your use of `AND` - [see here for full docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

but in short:

> $a and $b | And | TRUE if both $a and $b are TRUE.

Now let's take your code:

```
$var1 = true; # this is true
$var2 = 0; # this is false
$var3 = $var1 && $var2; # this will be false as $var2 is false

var_export($var3); # my machine shows false
var_export(true && 0); # this shows false as expected, 0 == false
var_export($var1 && $var2); # $var2 is false. This shows false
```

## Edit

The real reason is that `&&` has higher predence - which is why the above code does what I originally thought it should do with using `AND`. This is not the case, see here:

```
$g = true && false;

# The constant true is assigned to $h before the "and" operation occurs
# Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;

var_dump($g, $h);

# outputs:
# bool(false)
# bool(true)
```

So your code is doing as expected, just in a different way to how I first thought.